# Is there a way to make Visual Studio only offer relevant names?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intellisense

Currently when I press Ctrl+Space while having the cursor in the function parentheses Visual Studio Intellisense offers me everything it can possibly think of. Is there a way to restrict these names to names that make sense for that specific function / parameters / context?

I can click on the little button "Variables and Constants" which helps somewhat but I have to click on that every time this list is invoked.

(If I remember correctly Eclipse first offered only the relevant names/variables for the current context, then pressing Ctrl+Space again offered a wider range of names.)

[image]

Comment: VS does have the feature about giving priority to recommendations that match the current block area,  as the order about paramaters,classes,methods.What you provided is quite strange. And it should be comprehensive and not of the same type. Please try the following steps: 1) reset vs settings under Tools-->Import and Export settings-->reset vs settings 2) close  vs, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder , restart again to test. If it does not help, please provide a code sample to help us reproduce the issue.

Comment: Does it help to your issue？

Answer (score 1):

VS has the feature to give priority to variables, parameters, methods(mixed types) according to your current block domain rather than simply provide a single type.

[image]

So I think there is some problems with your environment, please try these:

**1)** disable any third party extensions under Extensions-->Manage Extensions-->Installed to check if there is an extension causing that.

**2)** reset vs settings under Tools-->Import and Export Settings-->Reset all settings

**3)** close VS, delete `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\ComponentModelCache` folder

**Also**, delete `.vs` hidden folder under your solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder.

restart VS to test again.

**4)** [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it if there is a new release version.